# Listing custom field values by most popular (in Wordpress)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

What I'm trying to achieve is: order values by count number for my two custom fields.

So if there are posts with:

5 cars

3 bicycles

1 motorbike

It would display like this: cars, bicycles, motorbike.

Basically removing duplicates and listing by the most popular custom field value.

Right now I have a code that list all of the custom field values (including duplicates):

```
<?php 
   

     $args=array(
       'posts_per_page' => 35,
       'caller_get_posts'=> 35
     );

     $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
     if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

       while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

           
   <?php echo usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-ticker'); ?> <?php echo usp_get_meta(false, 'ticker'); ?>


        <?php
       endwhile;
     }
   wp_reset_query(); 

 ?>
```

I need help. I know it can be done using array_unique and array_count_values but haven't figured out yet how to do that.

Comment: Your sample input is Unclear.  Please craft a [mcve].  What variables contain which values and what is their data structure?

Comment: If you don't know the answer, do not downvote it or comment it. I have already explained in a simple matter. There will be people with the same problem, and you are not helping at all.

Comment: You MUST create a [mcve] when you ask a question here.  You have poorly expressed your data.  Please [edit] to improve the clarity of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those that need a working solution:

1. Add this to functions.php:

```
global $wpdb;
$cities = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'your-custom-field'
GROUP BY meta_value 
ORDER BY c DESC" );
```

2. Add this code to where you want your popular values to be displayed:

```
<?php 
foreach( $cities as $city ) {
echo '' . $city . ' ';
} ?>
```

If you want to use values from two custom fields, just add OR:

```
global $wpdb;
$cities = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'your-custom-field1' or meta_key = 'your-custom-field2' 
GROUP BY meta_value 
ORDER BY c DESC" );
```

Enjoy.